# Implementing a two-way ordered list, how do I return a pointer so that it can be given a value?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, return

I have to implement a two way ordered list at a specific way, and I got stuck. I have a Bag class that has an Element class inside it. Now the problem is when I want to place an item inside the bag.

An element has a key (its value), a pointer to the smaller element (_down), and one to the larger (_up). When I put a new element inside the bag the code is the following (names translated so it's easier to understand)

```
void Bag::put(int e) {
    if(_item_count==0){
        Element *element = new Element(e, nullptr, nullptr);
        _bot = element;
        _top = element;
    }else{
        Element *p = _bot;
        while(e > p->key()){
            p = p->up();
        }
        Element *element = new Element(e, p, p->down());
        p->down() = element;
    }
}
```

So the problem is that p->down() is not assignable. I guess I should return the pointer by reference, but I don't know how to do that.

down() function

```
Bag::Element *Bag::Element::down() {
    return _down;
}
```

I tried putting & at great many places, but I just can't figure out how to make it all work.

Here's the full code if needed, but it's variables are mostly Hungarian, I'll provide translation if needed.
[Header on the left, cpp on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIT1E.png)

Comment: Hmm I am concerned... what if you add 2 to your list first then 3? e would be bigger then 2, and therefore p = p->up(), but the p->up() element should be null, so your p->key() would be dereferencing null wouldn't it?

Comment: I haven't yet worked on the actual procedure of putting it in when I asked the question, I just wanted to make it work. But you are right, the code I posted here is not final yet (not even close to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return a non-const lvalue reference to pointer which is good to be assigned to:

```
Bag::Element *&Bag::Element::down() {
    return _down;
}
```

And perhaps you should also provide a const overload:

```
Bag::Element * const &Bag::Element::down() const {
    return _down;
}
```

Of course you should update your class declaration accordingly.

And also you may consider using a struct for such simple classes like Element while making pointer fields public (which is the default access control for structs. Typically you won't get bashed for doing this in C/C++, unlike in Java where people tend to insist on using private fields and getter/setters even for super simple classes. (I'm not saying this good or bad, just a sort of convention.)

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the pointer directly:

```
p->_down = element;
```

Note that you are only modifying the "down" pointer of the next element. You also need to modify the "up" pointer of the previous element.

Note also that your new element may be the first or the last element in the list, you should handle these cases specially. Once you do that, you may discover that special handling of the empty list is unnecessary.